# In Python, why does installing SciPy package after removal not work?

Tags: python, scipy

I have problems with SciPy package. I tried to use ndimage from the scipy package this way:

```
from scipy import ndimage
```

But it had some problems with dll and etc (this issue neither have a lot of information, so I decided to uninstall SciPy and to install it again). I had used pip uninstall. But now when I am making an install it shouts:

[image]

And when I do pip freeze it doesn't show SciPy at all. Can someone tell me what is the matter?

P.S.

The scipy directory appears in Pycharm including the ndimage directory

Comment: Hi Eli. If an experienced editor/user edits your post and cites a reason, my advice would be not to disregard that change in a subsequent amendment. In particular, we do not add home-made tags to titles - we have a tagging system for that. This has been [discussed by the community here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495).

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot I guess that you're on Windows and you are trying to install `scipy` with `pip`. As `scipy` has a bunch of C extensions that need compilation, it won't work unless you have Visual Studio installed on the same computer. If that's not an option, you can download a precompiled version of `scipy` either from [the official site](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) or from the [wonderful page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) by Christoph Gohlke, or you can download one of the Python distributions like [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) or [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which have their own package manager allowing to easily download and install precompiled packages.

UPDATE: It seems that you're already using Anaconda, so simple `conda install scipy` from the command line should do the trick.

Comment: Then you have to install needed libraries first, like `blas` and `lapack`. Use  `conda`; it'll download `mkl` for you

Comment: I have already conda, When I enter: "pip install conda", I receive: "Requirments already satisfied: conda in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages"

Comment: I mean, use `conda` *instead of* `pip` to install scipy, as it will automatically download and install the precompiled version of scipy and all the relevant libs. I updated the answer; did you notice?